# How do I deal with the reledmac warning "\advanceline produced a line number less than zero"?

Tags: warnings, reledmac

I'm working on a file that, when compiled, produces dozens of examples of the following warning:

`\advanceline produced a line number less than zero.`

The thing is, the command \advanceline doesn't appear anywhere in the file, and on top of that I've suppressed line numbers through the whole document.

Obviously since it's a warning I can proceed without dealing with it, but this doesn't appear anywhere in the reledmac documentation. What does this error mean?

Comment: can you post a small example that shows the problem, hard to debug otherwise

Comment: \advanceline is for example called by \skipnumbering which is called by quote and other environments